# Installing .NET 7 preview breaks MAUI build

Tags: maui, .net-maui, .net-7.0

Since installing the .net 7 preview I can no longer build .net maui projects. I've uninstalled the preview and deleted the bin/obj files but still can't debug. The error's i'm getting are:

```
'{directory}/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    267
```

After trying dotnet restores and uninstalling/reinstalling .net components i now can't even click debug and get the error: [image: visual studio unable to start debugging the startup project cannot be launched...]

**Update**
I uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio and .net and got it working, momentarily. But now I'm getting the same errors again. I close and re-open Visual Studio or uninstall/reinstall components and then maybe get a different error like this one:

```
Manifest file at 'obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android-arm64\staticwebassets.build.json' not found. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets
```

Or no option to debug android at all:
[image: no android option]

I think this is related to my other open question: [.Net MAUI Blazor - can't click anything - "No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff", android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760662/net-maui-blazor-cant-click-anything-no-package-id-ff-found-for-id-0xfffff)

Answer (score 3):

I think .NET 7 RC1 will be the first version that also has the .NET MAUI workload installed.

You can have .NET 7 installed and still work with .NET MAUI (which will then operate on .NET 6) by using a `global.json` file.

In the working directory of you .NET MAUI project open a command-line and type: `dotnet --list-sdks`. From the resulting list pick the latest .NET 6 version. Let's say that is `6.0.400`, but it can be different for you.

Now in the same directory still, type: `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version=6.0.400`.

This will create a file `global.json` that pins the version of .NET to be used to the version you specify.

For more information on the `global.json` file, read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: Thanks (again) @Gerald, I ended up doing a full uninstall/reinstall to get it working again. Regardless, I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: Hmmm the problem is back and I tried your suggestion to no avail, unfortunately - see update

Answer (score 1):

1. Downgrading from 6.0.401 to 6.0.400 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73760461/1662619) seems to
   be a solution
2. Then I had to manually update the gloabl.json file to
   point to 6.0.400.
3. Then I had to open & close visual studio and do a
   dotnet restore.
4. Then I could debug on windows (be sure the framework
   selected in the dropdown is (net6.0 windows) otherwise you'll get
   that popup.

However I still can't debug android as there's no selectable option and when I manually run

```
dotnet run-f:net6.0-android -c:Release
```

I get there error: `error MSB4044: The "AndroidSignPackage" task was not given a value for the requried parameter "KeyPass"`

Comment: Won't that globally keep you pinned to SDK 6?

Answer (score 0):

My symptoms were:

1. I could not build a .NET 6 MAUI app and debug on a physical android device after updating to .NET 7. Please note that I also did try with the emulator. However, I did not try to build and run to any other platform.
2. My errors were:

```
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(376,5): error NETSDK1127: The targeting pack Microsoft.Android is not installed. Please restore and try again.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(376,5): error NETSDK1127: The targeting pack Microsoft.Maui.Core is not installed. Please restore and try again.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(376,5): error NETSDK1127: The targeting pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls is not installed. Please restore and try again.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(376,5): error NETSDK1127: The targeting pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials is not installed. Please restore and try again.
```

Strange enough, it seems somehow my SDK for Android API 31 somehow was either never installed or was uninstalled during the upgrade. I'm 99% sure it was installed because I have targeted that API for over 3 months now. Well, it turns out it wasn't, so I installed the API through the Android SDK manager, and now it works.