# .Maui Static Web Asset Build issue

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Manifest file at 'obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android-x86\staticwebassets.build.json' not found. MauiApp3 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets 680

I am struggling to get the Android application working. My Windows form will build but I receive the above error for arm, arm-64, and x86-64 as well. I just hit create project and try running right after with no changes.

My android SDK should be correctly matching. I have the 31.2.1 Android emulator and Android 11.0 (API 30) O.S. The emulator I create is the Pixel 5 11.0 Android.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Thijs for your answer :),
but the solution doesn't work for me, so I go to the shared link and performed below steps:

Step 1: Download and install the dotnet-sdk-6.0.400-win-x64 from [link](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9a1d2e89-d785-4493-aaf3-73864627a1ea/245bdfaa9c46b87acfb2afbd10ecb0d0/dotnet-sdk-6.0.400-win-x64.exe)

Step 2: Goto SDK folder (C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk) and rename the folder 6.0.401 to 6.0.401_Backup
[image]

Then it's worked for me.

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10102#issuecomment-1249355969)

Comment: I did this and then had to manually update the globaljson file and restart visual studio. Now i get an error: "The recipe file "~\bin\Debug\net6.0-android\projectname.build.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project."

Answer (score 2):

you have to add this to your .csproj file to fix this issue. Mind you this is a workaround while microsoft fixes this issue permanently.

```
<Target Name="TempFixBeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\staticwebassets.build.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android-arm\staticwebassets.build.json" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\staticwebassets.build.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android-arm64\staticwebassets.build.json" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\staticwebassets.build.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android-x64\staticwebassets.build.json" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\staticwebassets.build.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android-x86\staticwebassets.build.json" />
</Target>
```

sadly even on github, this is how you solve this. see this link 
[VS 17.3.4 Breaks Android build](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10102)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following issue on GitHub fixed it: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10102#issuecomment-1246388109.

Make sure to download dotnet 6.0.400 and then in your project folder run the following command:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 6.0.400
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing Maui workload execute below command. It should resolve this error.

```
dotnet workload install maui
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy staticwebassets.build from 
**obj\Debug\net6.0-android\staticwebassets.build.json** 
and paste into

- obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm
- obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-arm64
- obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-x64
- obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-x86

Answer (score 0):

If anyone come here in the future, if you have a MAUI class library, you may want to check if you accidentally leave a wrong TargetFrameworks:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Others -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0</TargetFrameworks> <!-- Remove this -->
    </PropertyGroup>
```

I accidentally have that one and the library project can still build but the project that consumes it would fail.