# Project builds in VS, but not in Azure Pipeline, help understanding the error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines

We have created a new pipeline for one of our applications to be compiled as an Artifact, a windows executable. Normally, this application is run through a Docker pipeline.
The Docker pipeline works 100%, and the same Windows Artifact pipeline is used for other projects, where it works.

The pipeline is set up to use

```
pool:  
  vmImage: ‘windows-latest’

variables:
  name: runtimeIdentifier  
  default: win-x64
```

It goes through the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task steps of restore, build, test and publish.  It fails at the publishing, which looks like this

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '${{Parameters.buildProjects}}'
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --no-restore --no-build -r ${{Parameters.runtimeIdentifier}} --self-contained true --nologo -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) -p:DebugType=embedded'
    zipAfterPublish: True
```

Here's the error message:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(658,7): 
error : Manifest file at 'obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\staticwebassets.build.json' not found. 
[D:\a\1\s\src\FieldPlug\ProductLine\Product\Product.csproj]
```

Here is the output from the Pipeline in DevOps:

```
Starting: Publish
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.216.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish D:\a\1\s\src\FieldPlug\ProductLine\Product --configuration Release --output D:\a\1\a\SNMP --no-restore --no-build -r win-x64 --self-contained true --nologo -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -p:Version=1.8.3-beta3-152-snmp -p:DebugType=embedded
**C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(658,7): error : Manifest file at 'obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\staticwebassets.build.json' not found. [D:\a\1\s\src\FieldPlug\ProductLine\Product\Product.csproj]**
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ 'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\FieldPlug\\ProductLine\\Product' ]
Finishing: Publish
```

Here are some things from the csproj which might be relevant

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<DockerfileContext>.. \.. \..</DockerfileContext>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>False</GenerateDocumentationFile>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-musl-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>False</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
<StartupObject></StartupObject>
```

As I mentioned, we have another application which uses the exact same build pipeline which has always run fine, but it’s not a web project and it’s not targeted towards both Linux and Windows like this.

I suspect there may be some funny business going on with the targeting, and it’s suspicious that the error comes from a Dot Net SDK version 7, when the target is . Net6. Also, it’s referring to Razor, which we don’t use for this. Not sure if it’s relevant, but here are the Microsoft packages we are using for the Project.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.4" NoWarn="NU1605" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.4" NoWarn="NU1605" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.15.1" />
```

Hopefully someone who is more proficient about this will understand what is going on here and thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's related to and/or potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710631/maui-static-web-asset-build-issue

Comment: And: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10102

Comment: Do you have a task that sets the .NET SDK in your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jessehouwing for the comment.

The error indicates that `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` NuGet package is missing in `.csproj` file.

Install the latest `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` NuGet package.

Try to clean the build and run again.

I have found the similar issue for [`android-x64`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-failed-with-error-Manifest-file-a/10144594), even it suggests the same as the link provided by `jessehouwing` to install the latest dotnet SDK.

Either install the SDK from [Visual Studio Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), build locally and run the pipeline.

***OR***

We can install with in the pipeline task by adding the new step before build as mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines).

```cs
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET SDK Latest'
  inputs:
    version: 'x.x'
```

> ```yaml
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(658,7):
> error : Manifest file at  'obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\staticwebassets.build.json' not found. 
> [D:\a\1\s\src\FieldPlug\ProductLine\Product\Product.csproj]
> ```

Please refer @[github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42200#issuecomment-1155948604) for the Workaround.